# Problem when reading file (server.log) with java

Tags: java, file

I am trying to search the log file with some sentences and then passing to a map, but its not working properly. Even the word "bow" is there in log it is telling failed.

Trying to search the server.log file for values of `test_input1, test_input2 ...` even though the value is there it is printing failed

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    public class Sample {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String filePath = "C:\\Users\\xxxxxxxx\\jboss-6.0.0-final\\server\\default\\log\\server.log";
            String test_input1 = "some meaningful log";
            String test_input2 = "bow";
            String test_input3 = "bat";

            Map<String, String> test_results = new HashMap<String, String>();
            BufferedReader br = null;
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("File ---> " + line);

                    if (line.equalsIgnoreCase(test_input1)) {
                        test_results.put("Test Case 1", "passed");
                    } else {
                        test_results.put("Test Case 1", "failed");
                    }

                    if (line.equalsIgnoreCase(test_input2)) {
                        test_results.put("Test Case 2", "passed");
                    } else {
                        test_results.put("Test Case 2", "failed");
                    }

                    if (line.equalsIgnoreCase(test_input3)) {
                        test_results.put("Test Case 3", "passed");
                    } else {
                        test_results.put("Test Case 3", "failed");
                    }
                }

                System.out.println("Summary of test cases: ");

            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : test_results.entrySet()) {
                if (entry.getKey().contains("Test Case 1")) {
                    String testresult1 = entry.getValue();
                    System.out.println("Test Case 1 Result ===> " + testresult1);
                } else if (entry.getKey().contains("Test Case 2")) {
                    String testresult2 = entry.getValue();
                    System.out.println("Test Case 2 Result ===> " + testresult2);
                } else if (entry.getKey().contains("Test Case 3")) {
                    String testresult3 = entry.getValue();
                    System.out.println("Test Case 3 Result ===> " + testresult3);
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found in path: " + filePath);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)
                    br.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Exception while closing bufferedreader " + e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0):

your else logic in adding to the map is changing the value every time in the map. meaning for every time you are processing the line the else modifies the value in the map for all the key in the map

Itr 1 
T1 pass
t2 fail
t3 fail

Itr 2 
T1 fail (due to else)
t2 fail 
t3 pass

so if only two iteration exists then the final value would be from itr 2

Comment: Thanks for letting me know the problem. Very helpful.